# Why is the ContentType property on the Request Header Null?

Tags: c#, http-headers, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I am using Fiddler to compose a call to my Web API service. The call is coming through and I am debugging it in the controller. However, the `Request.Content.Headers.ContentType` is `null`. However when I inspect the object, I can see `Content-Type: application/xml;` like below:

```
?Request.Content.Headers
{Content-Length: 40039
Content-Type: application/xml;
}
    base {System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders}: {Content-Length: 40039
Content-Type: application/xml;
}
    Allow: {}
    ContentDisposition: null
    ContentEncoding: {}
    ContentLanguage: {}
    ContentLength: 40039
    ContentLocation: null
    ContentMD5: null
    ContentRange: null
    ContentType: null
    Expires: null
    LastModified: null
```

What do I need to do to be able to inspect the `ContentType` value and have it populated?

**EDIT:** Here is the method signature for my Post method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyMethodDTO message)
```

`MyMethodDTO` is just a simple DTO class with getters/setters that are *all* strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing semicolon in the content type is invalid. Try sending:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

instead.

The HTTP spec defines a media type as:

```
media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
```

so there should only be a semicolon right before a media type parameter

Comment: Oddly I added it `;` so call would go through but that was a mistake. When I remove it, I get the following error: `No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MyMethodDTO' from content with media type 'application/xml'` I updated OP with method signature.

Comment: Figured this out - I was using XMLSerializer being registered in Global.asax as opposed to DataContractSerializer. When I removed registration of using XMLSerializer and went back to DataContractSerializer along with removing `;` from `Content-type` as you mentioned, it worked. I can spin up a new question, but if you don't mind, why can I not use XMLSerializer with XML in Post?

Comment: Check the ModelState property on the controller for deserialization errors. Likely, something went wrong when deserializing using XmlSerializer.